# Reading a Attribute name based on attribute value from xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get the node names based on the attribute values, but I am not able to proceed much on this, if anyone can help me on this.

I have the sample xml as below:

```
<ns0:Person xmlns:ns0="http://temp.poc">
   <name>
      <value>temp</value>
      <status>T</status>
   </name>
   <age>
      <value>tempval</value>
      <status>F</status>
   </age>
   <cellNumber>
      <value>9971760613</value>
      <status>T</status>
   </cellNumber>
   <city>
      <value>Bangalore</value>
      <status>F</status>
   </city>
   <ApplicationAccess>
      <value>value_0</value>
      <status>T</status>
   </ApplicationAccess>

</ns0:Person>
```

Based on the Status , where status = "T" , I need the node names as output.
for eg :

```
assistant
cellNumber
ApplicationAccess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `XmlDocument` and `XPath`, like this:

```
string xml = @"
   <ns0:Person xmlns:ns0='http://temp.poc'>
       <name>
           <value>temp</value>
           <status>T</status>
       </name>
       <age>
         <value>tempval</value>
         <status>F</status>
      </age>
         <cellNumber>
            <value>9971760613</value>
            <status>T</status>
         </cellNumber>
     <city>
       <value>Bangalore</value>
       <status>F</status>
    </city>
    <ApplicationAccess>
       <value>value_0</value>
       <status>T</status>
    </ApplicationAccess>

  </ns0:Person>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//status[text() ='T']");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.ParentNode.Name);
}
```

output will be names of those nodes whose child node `status` has `T` as innerText.

```
name
cellNumber
ApplicationAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `XDocument` (which I prefer over `XmlDocument`):

```
    var root = XDocument.Load(...).Root; // the <ns0:Person> XElement
    var namesOfElementWithStatusT = root.Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Elements().Any(e1 => e1.Name == "status" && e1.Value == "T"))
        .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName)
        .ToList();
```